# Flutter error involving operator not defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I'm following this tutorial but I'm currently getting this error

`error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'. (undefined_operator at [chat_app_tutorial] lib\views\search.dart:33)`

Please I've been having this bug for over 2days now. I've checked here and I've been researching online but I've not seen anything that has worked so far. This is the line of code I'm getting the error from.
I'm not sure what part of my code is needed to be able to help me so I'll just put everything.

````
import 'package:chat_app_tutorial/widgets/widget.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController searchTextEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot;

  initiateSearch(){
    databaseMethods.getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text).then((val){
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshot = val;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget searchList(){
    return searchSnapshot != null ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return SearchTile(

            userName: searchSnapshot.docs[0].data["name"],
            userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[0].data["email"],
          );
        }
    ) : Container();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initiateSearch();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarMain(context),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Color(0x54ffffff),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: searchTextEditingController,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                          ),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Search username",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white54
                            ),
                            border: InputBorder.none
                          ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        initiateSearch();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 40,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                const Color(0x36ffffff),
                                const Color(0x0fffffff)
                              ]
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          child: Image.asset("assets/images/search_white.png")
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              searchList()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userName;
  final String userEmail;
  SearchTile({this.userName, this.userEmail});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text(userName, style: simpleTextStyle(),),
              Text(userEmail, style: simpleTextStyle(),)
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
            child: Text("Message"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: I don't see which line the error is being reported on.  I don't believe it's in the code you posted.  Anyway, the error you're getting means that you're trying to call `[]` on a *function* that *returns* a `Map`, not on a `Map` itself.  Wherever you're getting that error, you need to invoke the function first.

Comment: I'm sorry I probably made mistake while copying or pasting. I've edited it. Can you guide me through how can I go about what you suggested? Please check the code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is complaining about:

> ```dart
>  return SearchTile(
>
>   userName: searchSnapshot.docs[0].data["name"],
>   userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[0].data["email"],
> );
> ```

[`searchSnapshot.docs[0].data`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) is a *function* that returns a `Map`.  You need to *call* that function first.

You probably want `searchSnapshot.docs[0].data()['name']` and `searchSnapshot.docs[0].data()['email']`.

Even better would be to avoid calling `data()` multiple times:

```dart
var data = searchSnapshot.docs[0].data();
return SearchTile(userName: data['name'], userEmail: data['email']);
```